# remove data sent to UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am creating a calculator app that has a backspace button just incase the user accidentally typed in a number. Is there a way to remove the last thing that was sent to the UILabel?

sure, I am adding my code to show what I am currently doing,

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
    if ([digit isEqualToString:@"."] && !_decimalPressed){
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
        self.historyDisplay.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
        self.decimalPressed = YES;
    }
    else if (!_isUserInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber){
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.historyDisplay.text = digit;
        self.isUserInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
    else if (![digit isEqualToString:@"."]){
        self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
        self.historyDisplay.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
    }
}
```

This how I am trying to get delete the last element

```
- (IBAction)backSpace:(id)sender {



}
```

Comment: how about adding a bit of code to your question to show how you are adding digits to your "`UILabel`"?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the last character from the string set inside your label.  Example code:

```
int numChars = myLabel.text.length;
NSString* truncatedString = [myLabel.text substringToIndex:(numChars - 1)];
mLabel.text = truncatedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString * stringToModify = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: self.display.text];
if(stringToModify && ([stringToModify length] > 0))
{
    [stringToModify deleteCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange([stringToModify length] - 1, 1)];
    self.display.text = stringToModify;
    [stringToModify release]; // if and only if NOT using ARC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)backPressed:(id)sender {
    self.display.text=[self.display.text substringToIndex:[self.display.text length] -1];
    if ([self.display.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.display.text isEqualToString:@"-"]){
        self.display.text = @"0";
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber=NO;
    }

}
```

Added in some common logic into the code. If you reach the last number and back space again, it will return the display text as 0. Since it's a calculator, assuming you have created the negative sign ( +/- ), if you are left with `-`, you will want to delete it and place it with 0 as well. Therefore if everything is relinquish back to 0, you will want to set your `userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber` to NO as well.